# What kind of software shows one what files are beeing installed on the HDD during .exe or .msi install process?

Tags: installation, registry, windows-installer, exe, sandbox

I remember having seen a windows software that shows one (in realtime) what files are beeing installed/extracted on the HDD and what keys are written in the registry during an .exe or .msi install process, but I don't remember what kind of software it was.

Was is maybe some kind of sandbox or a sysinternals tool?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think the sysinternals suite has utilities for recording changes from filesystem and registry (regmon and filemon).

Answer (score 1):

Its a sysinternals tool that I use, called Process Monitor. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 0):

As I found out there are tools developed exactly for this purpose. Namely:

- [SpyMe Tools](http://www.lcibrossolutions.com/spyme_tools.htm)
- [Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/total-uninstall.php)
- [What Changed](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php)

Sysinternals tools are great too, but you have to use good filters if possible otherwise, you'll have an extreme information overflow.